# C program without output in shell or in bash

Tags: c, bash, shell

Here is my C program (mycd):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int ac, char * av[]){
    char * dir;
    int t;
    if (ac < 2){
        dir = getenv("HOME");
        if (dir == 0)
            dir = "/tmp";
    } else if (ac > 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [dir]\n", av[0]);
        return 1;
    } else
        dir = av[1];
    t = chdir(dir);
    if (t < 0){
        perror(dir);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So after run when i type in shell o in bash `./mycd` i get nothing.

Why ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a full code? Where are the includes? Is it compiling without errors/warnings?

Comment: You cannot change the working directory from another process. That's why `cd` is a shell builtin, not an external command.

Comment: You might want to check your if statements involving the number of arguments. Try running your code with two sets of characters after it separated by spaces. for example: `/mycd something whatever`

Comment: It is compiling without errors. It's a correct program. I'd like just to know why i get nothing when i type it in bash o in shell

Comment: `ac` will be `1` so `dir` will point to the value of the `HOME` environment variable or will be `"/tmp"`. Both of those are likely to succeed when passed to `chdir`, so that's why `chdir` isn't returning `-1`, so `perror` is not called.

Comment: @Yoan15 What did you expect it to do?

Comment: okay Ian Abbott, thank you for your answer but i'd like to make an internal command mycd whith output

Comment: How i can do an internal command mycd with output in shell o bash ?

Comment: Now it's ok. Thank you ;)

Comment: Why when i try to put in shell "./mycd something", i have this output something : No such file or directory ?